# Tomcat Class Not Found - Servlet

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I am having a strange problem in deploying a basic web app through Eclipse and Tomcat

The error -

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet DeCommServlet

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.authentication.DeCommServlet
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
```

However, the application still gets to the DeCommServlet doPost() method and tomcat stays deployed but with that error.

Servlet:

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>DeCommServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.authentication.DeCommServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet> 

<!--  Servlet Mappings -->

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DeCommServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The servlet class is the correct link but still getting this error. I have nothing in any of the lib folders, but in the application properties I have the Apache Tomcat Lib added in Build Path >> Libraries

Has anyone seen this before?

Code for DeCommServlet:

```
@WebServlet("/DeCommServlet")
public class DeCommServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public DeCommServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("sdf");
    System.out.println("ddd");
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    request.getUserPrincipal().getName();   
    response.sendRedirect("http://www.google.com"); 
}
```

New Class Path[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubpGM.png)

Comment: Did you try to clean your project and rebuilt it?

Comment: I've tried cleaning, re-building and building it as a brand new project, still the same result.

Comment: Can you add the code of your DeCommServlet? You should also check that your "classes" directory is well spelled.

Comment: Added above ^^ - Just some test code in the doPost to debug

Comment: The code of the servlet you added does not show whether the class `DeCommServlet` is located in the package `com.authentication` or not...

Comment: Just added an image to show the package path ^^

Comment: Why is the "classes" directory in a "build" directory? Try removing the "build" directory and just keep the "classes" one.In fact, where are all the others mandatory directories of a web app (WEB-INF especially)?

Comment: shouldn't you be compiling to `<WebContent>/WEB-INF/classes` instead of into `build/classes` ?

Comment: how do you run your servlet? did you create a server in eclipse and said run on server?

Comment: Yeah, I created a Tomcat server and edited the web.xml to set my default Servlet for a basic login system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the deployment assembly that was causing the issue. Added the lib folder and we are good to go! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is how your webapp should look like :

```
> DeCommGlobal
> |-->src
>      |-->com
>           |-->authentication
>                      |-->DeCommServlet.java
> |-->META-INF
> |-->WEB-INF
>     |-->classes
>     |-->lib
```

Comment: The build path was the default that was supplied by Eclipse. I have added the classes folder under WEB-INF and changed the build path to build into that folder, but still getting the same error.

Comment: I have just replaced the image withthe new structure that I have. Still seeing the same error on build and now it isn't getting to the Servlet Class

Comment: Try to deploy and test your webapp in tomcat without using your IDE and let me know what happens.